# Make this SVG full width

Tags: html, css, svg

I have looked at general how-to's on SVGs. I think it is something specfic about this one. Here is the code.

```
<div><svg width=100% height=100% version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
width="299px" height="289px" viewBox="0 0 299 289" enable-background="new 0 0 299 289" xml:space="preserve">
  <path fill="url(#skyGradient)" d="M293.468,275.282c0,1.617-1.311,2.928-2.928,2.928H8.46c-1.617,0-2.928-1.311-2.928-2.928V13.718
  c0-1.617,1.311-2.928,2.928-2.928h282.08c1.617,0,2.928,1.311,2.928,2.928V275.282z"/>
  <g>
    <polygon fill="#7A5034" stroke="#7A5034" stroke-width="1.9519" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="
    67.032,174.069 96.807,225.639 126.581,277.21 67.032,277.21 12.484,277.21 39.258,225.639   "/>
    <polygon fill="#7A5034" stroke="#7A5034" stroke-width="1.9519" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="
    130.469,185.854 160.243,231.532 190.017,277.21 130.469,277.21 70.921,277.21 100.695,231.532   "/>
    <polygon fill="#7A5034" stroke="#7A5034" stroke-width="1.9519" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="
    195.858,154.624 225.632,215.917 255.406,277.21 195.858,277.21 136.309,277.21 166.083,215.917  "/>
    <polygon fill="#7A5034" stroke="#7A5034" stroke-width="1.9519" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="
    233.92,185.854 259.694,230.532 287.468,277.21 233.92,277.21 174.371,277.21 204.145,231.532  "/>
  </g>

  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="skyGradient" x1="100%" y1="100%">
      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="lightblue" stop-opacity=".5">
        <animate attributeName="stop-color" values="lightblue;blue;red;red;black;red;red;purple;lightblue" dur="14s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
      </stop>
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="lightblue" stop-opacity=".5">
        <animate attributeName="stop-color" values="lightblue;orange;purple;purple;black;purple;purple;blue;lightblue" dur="14s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
        <animate attributeName="offset" values=".95;.80;.60;.40;.20;0;.20;.40;.60;.80;.95" dur="14s" repeatCount="indefinite" />    
      </stop>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
```

Codepen:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JvaNeW

It must have to do with the "d=" line as far as I can tell but I can't seem to make sense of it or fix it.

Comment: I'm not very knowledgeable about SVGs yet, but I managed to get rid of the top, left and bottom margin for you, the right margin seems untouchable. I hope someone will give you a better solution :) [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/SirExotic/5wuo99dw/1/)

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out, it's

```
<path fill="url(#skyGradient)" d="M0,0L0,298L299,298L299,0L0,0z"></path>
```

which makes it full width and full height